# Angular auth guard fails if using search bar to navigate to a URI

Tags: angular

I have set up an injectable to handle auth in my application:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {SnackService} from '../../services/snack.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
      private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
      private snack: SnackService
  ) {}

  async canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    const user = await this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
    const isLoggedIn = !!user;
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      this.snack.authError();
    }
    return isLoggedIn;
  }
}
```

If I log into my application and redirect to a route by clicking a link i.e. `/projects/1` I get directed successfully once the guard check completes, if however I manually direct my browser to the same URI I get kicked back to the home page and told I'm not authorised (via my snack service, which redirects me to the login page and flashes a toast to say I need to be logged in)

If I modify my code to introduce some artificial slow down:

```js
  async canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    await this.timeout(300);
    const user = await this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
    const isLoggedIn = !!user;
    console.log(this.afAuth.auth.currentUser);
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      this.snack.authError();
    }
    return isLoggedIn;
  }
  timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
```

Then I can direct to the route via a link or manually hitting the URI through the address bar, leading me to believe that the application has been bootstrapped and loaded, but the auth guard is checked before the auth provider has finished its initialisation, resulting in a null check the first time.

Obviously I don't want to leave a 300ms delay on every page just to ensure protected pages cannot be navigated to without being authed.  Is there some way I can subscribe to the auth provider being initialised before I check the `currentUser` property?

Comment: don' t try to force async await. use observables

Comment: I'm new to the world of Angular, I've just came from React. I'll take a look at Observables, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, my work around was to return an Observable instead of Promise and utilize rxjs pipes like this:

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable < boolean > {
  return from(this.afAuth.auth.currentUser).pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
      const isLoggedIn = !!user;
      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        this.snack.authError();
      }
      return isLoggedIn;
    })
  );
}
```

let me know if it works

Comment: I'll take a look when I get home tonight, thank you :)